# Covariance in binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, covariance

Is the covariance between number of success and failure in a binomial distribution with parameters n and p, the same as the covariance between two binomial variables, which is
-np(1-p)?

Comment: What is the basis for saying "the covariance between two binomial variables is -np(1-p)? What are you assuming?

Comment: As a special case of multinomial distribution.

Comment: Then I don't see any distinction between the two things you're asking about - aren't both halves of the question asking exactly the same things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Binomial $\mathcal{B}(n,p)$ distribution, if $$X\sim\mathcal{B}(n,p)$$ is the number of successes, $$Y=n-X$$ is the number of failures. Therefore, $$\text{Corr}(X,Y)=-\text{Corr}(X,X)=-1$$

Then, since we know $$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Corr}(X, Y)\text{Stdev}(X)\text{Stdev}(Y)$$ and $$\text{Stdev}(X)=\text{Stdev}(Y)$$ we can calculate the covariance as
$$\text{Cov(X, Y)}=-Var(X)=-np(1-p)$$

Comment: If n is not given, only a probability of X, does the n term drop out? Or must we assume a value for n?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: If a belief is assessed that estimates the probability of an outcome, but no underlying dataset, must a confidence or a proxy for n also be estimated in order to compute the covariance?

Comment: The binomial distribution is *defined* w.r.t. n. You don't have a binomial distribution without n, you have a probability of an outcome but no samples.